# .ipa file not able to sideload the .ipa file extended apps

Tags: ios, iphone, ipa, sideloading

.ipa file not able to load into alt store it shows al server could not be found while it is connected to the pc and the alt server is installed in it and it also shows the error that it could not connect to the alt server when i have already made the conncections

The alt server should sideload the apps with .ipa file extension in the altserver in ios 16.1 and it should load the apps and run on the ios 16 and be able to complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.ipa file could not be connected to alt server because the particular reason could be the your ios device would not be connected properly with the pc which is running alt server or make sure that both the pc and the phone are connected to the same wifi before refreshing the apps or sideloading them and when they are connected together then the altserver would be able to sync the serverr and i with the i cloud it would be connected.